# How to show data dynamically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

okay, this a lit bit confusing, so I will try to be as much as understood.

I have an array of th tags that I am getting from MySql table. The reason for that is because I am sorting the columns of the table and update them in the database.

I am getting the data for the table from another table.

Here is the angular code:

```
 $scope.showLabelsFromData = false; // flag to know from where to take the th labels

var custFields = [{
"coulmn_name": "fullname",
"sort": false,
}, {
"coulmn_name": "phone",
 "sort": false
 }, {
"coulmn_name": "id_number",
 "sort": false
}, {
"coulmn_name": "email",
"sort": false
 }];

     var custFieldsFromData = [{

"coulmn_name": "phone",
"sort": false
}, {
"coulmn_name": "email",
"sort": false
}, {
"coulmn_name": "id_number",
  "sort": false
},{"coulmn_name": "fullname",
"sort": false,
}]

 $scope.labels = ($scope.showLabelsFromData) ? custFieldsFromData : custFields
```

The th labels are working well. My problem is it is not synchronized  with the td's when I change the flag $scope.showLabelsFromData to true, so the data will come from MySql. I don't know how to do it. Anyone have an idea?

Here is the full [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/wauj827y/13/)

Comment: Lots of unused code

Comment: Are you sure the number of TH and TD's are equal

Comment: Yes i'm sure the they are equal

Comment: I have remove the unused code the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/wauj827y/24)

Comment: @oded Can you post the code for that

Comment: @oded Based on your example, I see that everything is correct. I mean the code in fiddle

Comment: @CrazyMac look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/wauj827y/24) its all there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142448/discussion-between-crazymac-and-oded).

Comment: I have update the question